# Google Cloud Golang: How to parse project/zone/instance from instance URL?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using compute.NewRegionInstanceGroupManagersService's ListManagedInstances call which returns [ManagedInstance](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.51.0/compute/v1#RegionInstanceGroupManagersListInstancesResponse)'s.

ManagedInstance has a field [Instance](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.51.0/compute/v1#ManagedInstance) which is an instance url, like  `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-group-z0hf`

Now I would like to get more details about this particular instance. So using InstanceService's [Get call](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.51.0/compute/v1#InstancesService.Get), the function signature looks like this:

```
func (r *InstancesService) Get(project string, zone string, instance string) *InstancesGetCall
```

What's the best way to parse the instance URL (see above) into its project, zone and instance parts? Or is there a way of using another method to pass the instance URL directly?

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this,

- parse the URL to get its path
- split the path by slash component
- iterate the parts,
- locate static strings
- take the next value and assign it appropriately.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-group-z0hf"
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    parts := strings.Split(u.Path, "/")

    var project string
    var zone string
    var inst string

    for i := 0; i < len(parts); i++ {
        if parts[i] == "projects" && i+1 < len(parts) {
            project = parts[i+1]
            i++
        } else if parts[i] == "zones" && i+1 < len(parts) {
            zone = parts[i+1]
            i++
        } else if parts[i] == "instances" && i+1 < len(parts) {
            inst = parts[i+1]
            i++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(project, zone, inst)
}
//Ouptput:
//my-project us-central1-b instance-group-z0hf
```

Alternatively, use the route engine from gorilla to create a new pattern, apply the route to the url path and collect output results. But it is more complex and probably not justified.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are complex animals, the best way is using the library `url.Parse`. Then you can use a regex or split to extract the data you need from the path part.